# Column Space after Left-Multiplication by an Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and that $B$ is a full-rank $n\times p$ matrix, with $p<n$. Is it the case that the column space of $A^{-1}B$ coincides with the column space of $B$, that is, $\mathcal{C}(A^{-1}B)=\mathcal{C}(B)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a counter example. Let $A$ be the following $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$$

We now have:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}\frac 3 4 & -\frac 1 2 & \frac 1 4 \\ -\frac 1 2 & 1 & -\frac 1 2 \\ \frac 1 4 & -\frac 1 2 & \frac 3 4\end{matrix}\right]$$

Then, let $B$ be the following $3 \times 2$ matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Then, the column space of $B$ is the plane $z=0$, but the column space of $A^{-1}B$ clearly has vectors outside of this plane since the first column of $A^{-1}B$ has a non-zero z-coordinate, so the column spaces are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for the example. In this case $A$ is not positive definite. Is there a simple counter example for $A\succ 0$?

Comment: The multiplication by $A^{-1}$ is effectively changing basis in the range, so you would not expect the spaces to be identical. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ for any $a,b$ with $a+b\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you both, that resolved my question.